# Android Best Practice : Saving Complex Data from an App

Tags: android, performance, save

I work on an application which contains complex data, like user list, images, long ArrayList etc. I look for advices to save properly the data. I wonder if marshalling was safe or do you suggest me to use SQLite ? Because if I save an user created object in a file, I think that I couldn't open it if the object class changed (for exemple if you add a field to your class).
I have no idea what to do exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite is very powerful, but not always necessary. You can get along just fine by serializing your data to disk using something like [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) in many cases. If you're dealing with lots of data, SQLite probably the best bet, but as you observed, it's inflexible at times. You'll have to map your model objects to tables and then write upgrade logic when the structure of your models change.

I recommend starting with serializing/de-serializing your data to/from the disk to start. If the amount of data you need to handle makes this unwieldily, migrate to SQLite. If you do go that direction, look into [GreenDAO](http://greendao-orm.com/) or [OrmLite](http://ormlite.com/).

Comment: Gson seems a good idea to start with. GreenDao and OrmLite are intresting. I will keep these solutions in mind if I need to migrate to SQLite. Thank you for your answer (^_^).

Answer (score 0):

Use SQLite. It will process the data in the fastest way possible while creating the possibility to execute complex queries.